# Why do I get a citation undefined error?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I have a file named `references.bib` that has a reference like:

```
@article{suttonpaper,
  title={Learning to Predict by the Methods of Temporal Differences},
  author={RICHARD S. SUTTON},
  journal={Machine Learning 3:9 44},
  year={1988}
}
```

I am trying to use this in a latex file named `template.tex` in the same directory as `references.bib`.

I do:

```
\cite{suttonpaper}
```

and it gives an error saying `citation on page 1 undefined`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more after adding `\cite{suttonpaper}`?

Comment: Off-topic: Why is the author's name provided in all-caps? And why are `3`, `9`, and `44`  part of the `journal` field instead of in the `volume` and `pages` fields, respectively? (I think it should be `volume = 3` and `pages={9--44}`.) Finally, why is the `number` field missing entirely?

Comment: @Mico I run it multiple times. Here is the latex I am using : https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/style-and-template-for-preprints-arxiv-bio-arxiv/fxsnsrzpnvwc

Comment: @Mico Could you correctly describe the way I must be citing the paper : http://incompleteideas.net/papers/sutton-88-with-erratum.pdf

Comment: Note that the linked template shows the manual way to produce a bibliography (with `thebibliography`) and the BibTeX way (with `\bibliography`). From the link alone it is not clear what you are trying to do. If you did not change anything in the template w.r.t. bibliographies and references it will not pick up anything in `references.bib` because the `\bibliography{references}` is commented out and the manual bibliography is activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment up front: I don't use Overleaf, I don't even have an account there. Hence, I cannot access the URL you provided in a comment. If you wish people to see the code you work with, you should provide it as ASCII text in the body of your query rather than as a link to a site that's not easily and immediately accessible.

To retrieve the complete bibtex record without too much effort, I suggest you perform a Google search to find its webpage -- here: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00115009. Then, click on the "cite article" button in the upper-right corner and select "BibTeX" as the output method. You should get something like this -- note the separate `volume`, `number`, and `pages` fields. (There can be no valid reason for dumping these pieces of information into the `journal` field. The excuse "that's how my friends and/or coauthors do it" is *not* a valid reason...)

```
@Article{Sutton1988,
  author  = "Sutton, Richard S.",
  title   = "Learning to predict by the methods of 
            temporal differences",
  journal = "Machine Learning",
  year    = "1988",
  month   = "Aug.",
  day     = "01",
  volume  = "3",
  number  = "1",
  pages   = "9--44",
  issn    = "1573-0565",
  doi     = "10.1007/BF00115009",
  url     = "https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00115009"
}
```

Finally, here's an MWE (minimum working example) that uses the `IEEEtran` document class and the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, along with the `xurl` and `hyperref` packages. Be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more each time you add `\cite` instructions.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{References.bib}
@Article{Sutton1988,
  author  = "Sutton, Richard S.",
  title   = "Learning to predict by the methods of 
            temporal differences",
  journal = "Machine Learning",
  year    = "1988",
  month   = "Aug.",
  day     = "01",
  volume  = "3",
  number  = "1",
  pages   = "9--44",
  issn    = "1573-0565",
  doi     = "10.1007/BF00115009",
  url     = "https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00115009"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{Sutton1988}
\bibliography{References}
\end{document}
```